# In C++, why can't an object be freed when its pointer is out of scope?

Tags: c++, pointers, compiler-construction

Say I have a method, then `new` an object inside the method:

```
void MyMethod() {
  Obj* p = new Obj();
}
```

When the function ends, the pointer will be dropped because it's out of scope, and if I'm not returning the `p` pointer, that means there's no reference of this `Obj` object, why can't the compiler do the object deletion for us?

So there won't be a "memory leak" if people forget to do so.

Comment: If you want that behavior, you can write `Obj p;` and it will handle cleanup at the end of a method. But sometimes you need to be able to create an object whose lifetime doesn't neatly match a function's scope.

Comment: Determining when an object is leaked is a hard problem ("garbage collection"). For example, it's possible that `Obj` creates a thread and passes itself to the thread, and then deletes itself when finished. Deleting the `Obj` on exit from MyMethod would free the object prematurely.

Comment: okay, so the exception is with thread. I'm just trying to figure out why C++ designed this way, because seems obvious that if you don't call a thread and don't return it, there is no way to access this object outside of the function?

Comment: Having automatic garbage collection is a tradeoff for some amount of overhead / performance. C++ choose one way. Other languages choose the other way.

Comment: Didn't have to be a thread. Maybe `Obj` registers a callback, and when the callback occurs, it does some work and then deletes itself.

Comment: @L.Kai: You don't need threads to make analysis impossible. It's sufficient to call an external function and pass it the pointer as an argument. The compiler cannot know that the external function won't store the pointer in persistent memory somewhere, so it can't deallocate the memory the pointer points at. Of course, if the pointer is *never used*, then it should be possible to deallocate it. Indeed, it should be possible to completely eliminate it, including the pointless allocation. But I think it's fair to say that *most variables are used*. :-)

Comment: (In fact, the object's own constructor could keep a persistent pointer to the object, for example as a registry of that kind of object. That might seem like poor style, but it certainly is done, occasionally, and not just for debugging.)

Comment: @rici okay I got it, there are many ways to reference a pointer inside a function, so it's impossiable for compiler just to decide whether or not it's not used anymore.
that's the anser I need, thanks man!!

Comment: It's not about whether it's possible to analyze the situation. The rule is that when you create an object on the free store you're responsible for managing its lifetime. Full stop.

Answer (score 2):

It can with `std::unique_ptr`! Raw pointers aren’t really for every-day use in modern C++ you want this:

```
#include <memory>

void MyMethod() {
  std::unique_ptr<Obj> p = std::make_unique<Obj>();
   // no leak!
}
```

Or you can also just do `Obj p;` but I’m guessing you know that.

Answer (score 0):

Figuring out whether the pointer is or is not going out of scope at compile time is very hard.

Say you have code like this:

```
void bar(Obj* obj); //we do not know what this method does

int MyMethod() {
  Obj* obj = new Obj();
  bar(obj);
}
```

Can you delete `obj` at the end of `MyMethod`? The answer is no, because `bar()` might still use it. For example, `bar` could look like this:

```
void* someGlobalVariable;

void bar(Obj* obj) {
  someGlobalVariable = (void*) obj;
}
```

Then `MyMethod` may not delete the object, because it is still in use from `someGlobalVariable`. `bar()` also may not delete the object, because you do not want methods to randomly deallocate memory passed into them when you do not expect it. So the compiler can not help you here, you need to manage the memory yourself.

In general, we want to eventually free all memory we allocate. Since the compiler can not do this for us (at least not always), we need to do it manually. Now, we could design a compiler that has some rules for when it automatically inserts code deleting a pointer.

But such a compiler would be cumbersome to use in practice, because you would always need to remember the rules for when the compiler deletes the memory for you, versus when you need to do it yourself. And if you make the compiler more clever, you make existing programs wrong. So the designers of C picked the consistent option of "you must always free all memory you allocate yourself".